# Sequelize showing 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' for an update query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a booking appointment app using sequelize.

My database model is:

```
const sequelize = require('../util/database')
const User = sequelize.define('users',{
    id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        allowNull:false,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    name:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    },
    email:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    },
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }

})
module.exports = User;
```

I have set my phone number to be unique as to avoid duplicate users.

And my edit API is:

```
exports.editUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.id
        console.log(id)
        const { name, email, phone } = req.body
        if (!id) {
            res.status(404).json({ err: 'id not found' })
        }
        const result = await User.update({
            name,
            email,
            phone
        },
            { where: { id: id } },)
        res.status(200).json({ res: result })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ err: err })
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
>
> errors: [
> ValidationErrorItem {
> message: 'phone_UNIQUE must be unique',
> type: 'unique violation',
> path: 'phone_UNIQUE',
> value: '1234567890',
> origin: 'DB',
> instance: [users],
> validatorKey: 'not_unique',
> validatorName: null,
> validatorArgs: []
> }
> ],

`user.update` should overwrite the data at specific id. Why is it causing an error of duplicate entry as I am not creating a new but updating an existing entry?

I tried updating the present data in user table by `user.update()` and expecting to overwrite my present data in fieldwith new data at same id.

Comment: Did you try to get the generated SQL and execute it directly to check what ;s going on? Could it be that this phone value is already ib DB in the other user record?

Comment: my table contains only one user with this record and i am trying to edit that specific user only .

Comment: All in all did you try to execute the generated SQL query? Does it look correct?